# Unparseable date: "Apr 5, 2018" in Java

Tags: java, date, exception, unparseable

I want an output in `Month,Year` wise only but I'm getting a problem. It is an `Exception` of `Unparseable date: "Apr 5, 2018"`. I have stored the date in `Bill_Date` Column in `sqlite` and it has its format of `"Apr 5, 2018"` in its field. So how can I get only Month and year in that format `(Apr, 2018)` only. This is my code given below:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Demo2 {
    private static Connection con;
    private static String query;
    private static PreparedStatement PStat,PStat2;
    private static ResultSet res,res2;
    private static String Bill_Date;
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {
        con=Database.Database();
        query="select Bill_Date from DailySales where Bill_Date='Apr 5, 2018'";
        PStat=con.prepareStatement(query);
        res=PStat.executeQuery();
        while(res.next())
        {
        Bill_Date=res.getString("Bill_Date");
        }
        SimpleDateFormat month=new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM,yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
        SimpleDateFormat dateformat=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd,YYYY");
        Date date=dateformat.parse(Bill_Date);
        String MONTH=month.format(date);
        System.out.println(MONTH);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

It has this error.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Apr 5, 2018"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at Demo2.main(Demo2.java:34)
```

Comment: Ask yourself the question - how is `MMM-dd,YYYY` the same as `Apr 5, 2018`?

Comment: Unless you have complete control over the input strings, your enterprise is doomed to fail.  Date formats produced by random external programs vary too much for Java's dateformat classes to handle.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing a space in the formatter and you also have an extra `-`:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformat=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
```

---

Thanks [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636009/david-conrad)

Also it seems your year format is wrong. Use `yyyy` for the correct year format.

Comment: Wrong kind of year. Capital Y is a "Week year."

Answer (score 6):

Two problems:

1. Using capital `Y` means something called a ["week year"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), which is different than year.  Use `y`s instead.
2. You have a `-` in the format that doesn't exist in the date string.  Make the format have a space (or make the data have a `-`).

Use this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d,yyyy");
```

Comment: needs space after comma

Comment: @DavidConrad I noticed that after I posted, but it seems to work anyway.  Ideally and pedantically, yes, put that space in the format.  But it appears not to be necessary.